# Why is a duplicate record inserted when it should not be?

Tags: postgresql

Why does this command

```
insert into "deliveryLog" select * from temp_dellog where "deliveryID" < 15620652
```

give this output?

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "deliveryLog_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key ("deliveryID")=(15620652) already exists.
```

Both tables have identical structure, deliveryID is a bigint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a red herring.  When pgadmin gets disconnected midquery, it returns the last error again even if it was an entirely different command! :)